# Ubuntu Data recovery after Format

Tags: data-recovery

My Ubuntu was giving error so I thought to re-install it. I took backup of my project files and then re-installed Ubuntu 16 from a USB drive. After reinstalling I realized that I missed 2 of my projects to take backup. 
I searched for the data recovery software and found testdisk and photorec. But it says that data can be recover before any installation and these software needs to be installed on any other media.
My question is, as I've re-installed the Ubuntu, is it now possible to retrieve/restore the data? Secondly, I need to install the testdisk and photorec on another media i.e. USB drive?

Comment: If you hope to recovery any data off your current drive - stop using it at once.  Everything changed reduces the chances of getting data back.  You need to use other media as your system if you want any chance of getting data back.

Comment: I have dual boot system, the other is Windows 8.1, should I not even use Windows?

Comment: Depends on your windows setup, most likely windows use will not impair the recovery potential of your Ubuntu partition (normally windows users don't mount Ubuntu partitions; if you do that normally then don't; the partition should be accessed in read-only mode until data recovery has completed).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to install the testdisk and photorec on another media i.e. USB drive?

Yes, You first need to make a bootable USB drive that contains testdisk. You can do this by using another computer, or your windows partition. Then boot from the USB you have created and follow the instructions, for example https://www.maketecheasier.com/recover-data-and-partitions-for-free-with-testdisk/

I suggest you make an image of your Linux partion first, with https://www.maketecheasier.com/clone-drives-and-partitions-with-clonezilla/ and work from that image.